# How to change ViewCell items values?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a code like this:

```
class CustomCell : ViewCell
{
    private readonly Label _label;

    public static readonly BindableProperty DataProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Data", typeof(string), typeof(CustomCell), "Data");

    public string Data
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    ...

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        if (BindingContext != null)
        {
                _label.Text = Data;
        }
    }
}
```

It works just fine, when I use this code to pass value to it in ListView:

```
<customUi:CustomCell Data="{Binding Data}" />
```

However, sometimes I want to be able to change `Data` from `CustomCell` itself. When I change it simply by writing `this.Data = "new value";` the label text doesn't change. I could write simply `_label.Text = "new value";`, it works, but it just feels wrong. Also, changing `Data` and then calling `OnBindingContextChanged()` feels wrong as well.

What is the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you have created a bindable property called "Data" on your class. The property "Text" of the Label control is also bindable. So you can apply the same binding to it, and it should work as expected.
The common pattern is to have the binding context of your control contain the necessary properties, to which you would then bind the properties of individual controls.
So instead of binding to a Data property and then re-applying that property to the label, just edit the CustomCell itself and give the label's text property this same binding

```
<Label Text="{Binding Data}" />
```

You can even take specific objects from your viewmodel and pass them as binding context for the cell, so that the controls inside the cell always have the same structure to bind to

```
<customUi:CustomCell BindingContext="{Binding SomeItem}" />
//Assuming SomeItem is a property inside your VM, or binding context of wherever the CustomCell is
```

Now bind the label's text property and any other properties of any other controls inside the CustomCell to properties of SomeItem.

---

In case you really want to create a bindable property on the viewcell and then just pass it through to the label, you can also take whatever binding is applied to the "Data" property of the CustomCell on it's property changed event and apply the same binding to the Text property of the label. Though this should not be needed really.

Comment: if I need some formatting, for example if Data is decimal and I want it to be displayed in label in some particular way, I suggest I should use ValueConverter, right?

Comment: It's up to you. For things that I do in multiple places I definitely use a value converter, yeah. If I need something in once place only, i might actually override the on property changed and transform the value there or create a helper property of type string which auto transforms the value. all depends on your preference and the frequency at which you expect the prop to change. Static converter instance in the global dictionary is a safe choice.

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnPropertyChanged` method like:

```
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if (propertyName == "Data")
            _label.Text = Data;
    }
```

Comment: While  this will work, there is no need to manually update the text property and it amounts to nothing different than what the original poster already, correctly, claimed "feels wrong". Use data binding instead. See my answer